# How to set up no www on Route 53, site hosted by Glitch.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I’m trying to set up my site, www.jdipasquale.com to be found without including the www at the start. I’m confused on how to set this up in my Route 53. I heard I need to find some sort of IP or host name. My code for my site is also hosted by glitch.com, how can I set this up? I’ve tried using the project’s host name, jdipasquale.glitch.me for the record set value but it said it was an invalid character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website name `www.jdipasquale.com` resolves to IP address `206.51.242.1`.

```
~ $ host www.jdipasquale.com
www.jdipasquale.com is an alias for 1xqede0mi3f68p6m.shw.io.
1xqede0mi3f68p6m.shw.io has address 206.51.242.1
```

You can try to create an **A record** in Route53 for `jdipasquale.com` with value `206.51.242.1`. You will also have to add `jdipasquale.com` as an alias in *Glitch*, otherwise it throws "Not found" error.

However depending on how that *Glitch* service is implemented the IP *may* change in which case you will have to update the A record. Maybe quite often. That will need to be tested or ask the Glitch support.

Unfortunately you can't have a [**CNAME at the domain root**](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-cant-a-domain-s-root-be-a-cname-8cbab38e5f5c) like you do for `www.jdipasquale.com` which is quite a stupid design decision in the DNS protocol (not in Route53 but in DNS itself). That's why `jdipasquale.com` and `www.jdipasquale.com` records must be configured differently.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Okay, I’ll try this. But how do I add `jdipasquale.com` in Glitch?

Comment: I don’t know Glitch, sorry. I can only help with Route53.

Comment: Don’t worry about it. What I did now was add the A record. Then I set up jdipasquale.com with glitch, and it gave me another .shw.io url. I made a CNAME for jdipasquale.com pointing to the shw.io url, which was what I had to do, but it brought an error.

Comment: Resolve that new .shw.io to IP and use that for the domain root. That should work.

Comment: Thanks. I think it worked. Can you go to jdipasquale.com on you to check that it wasn’t just my browser cache? And also when I edit the code for my site it goes to both the www and non www?

Comment: Yep looks good :)